# What's the best way to save the sensor data to local machine for analysis?

Tags: windows-phone-7

HI,

I am building a small application using accelerometers on the phone. I hope I can get the accelerometer data from the phone and analyze them at my PC and then I can build a model based on these data and deploy the model on the phone.

But I just don't know how to get the data out of the phone.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing you could write to Debug when running from within Visual Studio.

Beyond that you'll need to send the data to a web service running on the local PC.

As a third alternative, you could save the data to IsolatedStorage on the device and then use http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/ to get this files off the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you log the data on the phone, you can later (say when you touch a button) send the data to a web service stored on your computer.

If you log the data in a string then your web service should expose a method that accepts a string input. It should be easy to setup and it is really easy to use from the phone, just use the Add Service Reference wizard to connect to it.